# event espresso CORS is wrong

Tags: wordpress, cors

I was hired to write a wordpress plugin which involves an ajax request to the website's eventespresso api.

I got it working fine locally (calling the live site's api from my local server), but when I activate the plugin on the live site, it throws:

> Failed to load http://example.com/wp-json/ee/v4.8.36/events: The
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://opt.local'
>   that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin
>   'http://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

My local domain is "http://opt.local", and the live site is http://example.com.

This error suggests to me that it only wants to allow access from my local setup, and not from the live site, which isn't even cross origin! Maybe I caused it to cache the wrong thing in development?

So a few more tests revealed that the cors settings are correct for everything except the specific route I need.

```
> curl -I "http://example.com/wp-json"
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com

> curl -I "http://example.com/wp-json/ee/v4.8.36"
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com

> curl -I "http://example.com/wp-json/ee/v4.8.36/events"
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://opt.local
```

I was able to make it work by using ee/v4.8.35 (a lower api patch version) but hopefully, there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I helped develop the EE4 REST API.

Ya it sounds like some issue where the webserver or a proxy or something is caching the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

There's no code in the EE4 REST API that controls that header, that's actually handled by the WP API (on which the EE4 REST API is built).

The relevant code is in `wp-includes/rest-api.php` in the function `rest_send_cors_headers()`. That calls `get_http_origin()`, whose value can be filtered using the filter `http_origin`.

So you might want to try adding something like

```
function my_plugin_force_correct_http_origin($http_origin) {
    return 'http://example.com';
}
add_filter('http_origin', 'my_plugin_force_correct_http_origin');
```

that will ensure the PHP code is sending the correct Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. 
If that doesn't resolve the issue, I would verify `rest_send_cors_headers()` is getting called at all (you could temporarily put a line like `echo 'called rest_send_cors_headers!';die;` inside that function to check).

If it is getting called, and my suggested filter doesn't help, you could try tagging your question with 'wordpress-rest-api'. Also, I would be curious to see if `http://example.com/wp-json/ee/v4.8.36/events?limit=50` has the same problem.